# Finding derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\lim\limits_{x\to\ 2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x^2-4}=4$ where $f(x)$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ and $g(X)=\frac{f(x)e^x}{1-x}$. What is $g'(2)$?

Comment: maybe the question should be, what is $g'(2)$?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any thoughts? Written any work down? Here's a hint you should be able to turn into an answer by yourself: use the product rule.

Comment: I did . I got $-f'(x)e^x$..then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving g(x) we get:
$$g'(x)=\frac{e^x}{(1-x)^2}(f(x)(2-x)+f'(x)(1-x))$$

From the limit given in the question we see 
$$4=\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{f(x)-f(2)}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\frac{f'(2)}{4}$$
So knowing that $f'(2)=16$ we get:
$$g'(2)=-16e^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\ 2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x^2-4}=\lim\limits_{x\to\ 2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=\frac14\lim\limits_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\frac14f'(2)=4\implies f'(2)=16$

$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)\: e^x}{1-x}=\frac{f'(x) e^x+f(x)\:e^x}{1-x}+\frac{f(x)\:e^x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{e^x}{(1-x)^2}(f'(x)(1-x)+f(x)(1-x)+f(x))$

$\therefore g'(2)=\frac{e^2}{(1-2)^2}(f'(2)(1-2)+f(2)(1-2)+f(2))=e^2(-f(2))=-16e^2$